# GCC OpenMP parallel for reduction MUCH slower than Visual Studio

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, visual-studio-2013, openmp

A friend of mine and I have encountered a performance problem regarding `parallel for reduction` in GCC.

The code:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    int tans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:tans)
        for (int id = 0; id < 10000; ++id) {
            tans++;
        }
    printf("%d\n", tans);
}
```

(This useless code is only used to demonstrate the problem)

When compiled with GCC (version 4.9.2 (tdm64-1)) and run on my 4-core 8-thread system (Win 8.1 64b), the code runs about 5s, while with `num_threads(1)` it runs only 0.5s.

I have also tried the same code on a 24-core system (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)), the parallel version is still very slow, and the running time is very unstable, ranging from 1s to 10s.

With Visual Studio 2013, the code always finishes almost instantly. The generated assembly code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ftfish/f8ffdb9106b82ae63925

What have I done wrong? Is it because of the overhead of `parallel for reduction`? Why is Visual Studio performing better? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I were a smart compiler, I'd convert that inner loop into `tans += 10000`. What assembly does Visual Studio generate?

Comment: I'm rather surprised that both compilers wouldn't reduce the entirety of that code to `printf("%d\n", 100000000);`.  What optimization levels were you using on each?

Comment: @DrewDormann -O2 (and -O3 the same) for GCC and Release for VS2013

Comment: @Mysticial I fail to decipher the assembly code, but it's here: https://gist.github.com/ftfish/f8ffdb9106b82ae63925

Comment: @Mysticial it seems VS is actually doing the reduction, but still runs instantly. Have I read it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

If your real code is about as simple as this code, you most likely lose a lot of opportunity for compiler optimization. `g++ -O3` generates the following assembly for the code you posted minus the OMP line:

```
.cfi_startproc
subq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
movl    $1000000000, %esi
movl    $.LC0, %edi
xorl    %eax, %eax
call    printf
xorl    %eax, %eax
addq    $8, %rsp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
ret
```

As you see, absolutely *nothing*  here is calculated at runtime, the loops are *both*  completely optimized away. Thus, the program finishes instantly. If you let the computation happen at runtime, you obviously increase it. [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df49007a2716b497) you can see that adding the OMP line actually makes computation happen at runtime, the generated assembly is too long to be pasted here.

**Edit:**

I tested the OMP code with both g++ and clang++ and can reproduce your problem (g++ ca. 0.3s, clang++ 0.006s, i.e. instant). clang does optimize both loops out, even with the OMP line. Since your code is perfectly fine, this is the fault of gcc's optimizer. It is now not clear if the gcc guys screwed up or if they followed a rational like "if the user writes OMP, they should have found out by measuring that the parallel version is faster. Do not optimize that away." I would put my money on the latter, but go and visit the gcc bugzilla if you want to make sure.

What remains is the conclusion I mentioned in the comment: **Measure everything.**

In this special case: If you want to target gcc and VC, just measure both variants in both environments and then ship the better one to your customer. If you feel like this is a gcc performance bug, you can still write a bug report for them.

A last remark:

If your real code is a double-loop like here, consider parallelizing the most outer one to save expensive OMP start-up procedures (but measure(!), this might of course be not helpful.)

Comment: Even for a unknown input, the compiler optimizes it to "add 1000000000". http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bcbe6c80779d0543

Comment: Thank you first. Could you please have a check of the assembly code generated by VS2013 in the comment on the question? I'm not sure whether VS is able to optimize even if the OMP line is there.

Comment: @ftfish I do not have or use any Microsoft Compiler. The results should be similar if not equal to what gcc does in simple cases like this. The point is that firing up 100000 parallel loops takes longer than one addition (surprise, surprise :D ). What we can learn from this: If in doubt, implement both and measure what is faster.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I'm not quite convinced though. As far as I can tell from the assembly code generated WITH the OMP line (as said, the code is given in the COMMENT on the question), VS is actually doing the reduction, and still runs instantly. Since the code is highly simplified, I feel that the only conclusion that can be drawn is that VS optimizes better than G++ in this case..

Comment: You could file a PR in gcc's bugzilla for the fact that openmp disables this optimization.